# Generalist badge wording isn't clear

Tags: discussion, support, badges, generalist-badge

The generalist badge (which, apparently, is now awarded, contrary to what other questions here on meta suggested) has a very unclear description: "Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags"

What are the "top 40 tags"? According to what ranking? If an answer has more than one tag, does it count towards 20? (i.e., could the badge theoretically be reached with only 4 answers?)

**Edit:** also, does the "15 total score" apply to each of the 20 tags, or to the total sum? I suspect the latter, otherwise it seems very easy.

Comment: Not a canonical answer, but the top 40 tags are most likely the 40 first ones on this list: http://stackoverflow.com/tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### What are the "top 40 tags"? According to what ranking?

Number of questions with that tag, the order they appear in the [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags)

#### If an answer has more than one tag, does it count towards 20?

I would expect so, there's no reason it wouldn't. It's unlikely that you could actually manage it with 4 answers though, since the top tags are mostly individual languages and it's tough to find questions tagged with five different languages

Comment: Even after that it's not quite clear for me. Does it mean, that should exists 20 tags (in top 40) that for any of this tag my sum of answers for this tag is >= 15?